# Symfony DQL Postgresql group by isnt working

Tags: postgresql, symfony, dql

I have just switched from mysql to postgresql and my working dql queries stopped working.

Here is my dql

```
SELECT p
        FROM AppBundle:Photo p
                JOIN AppBundle:Like l  WITH p = l.photo
           WHERE p.isModerated = :isModerated
            AND p.isActive = :isActive
                        AND p.category IN(:categories)
                        AND p.creationDate <= :begin
                        AND p.creationDate >= :end
                        GROUP BY p.id
            ORDER BY l.creationDate DESC
```

Getting the next error

```
SQLSTATE[42803]: Grouping error: 7 ERROR: column "l1_.creation_date" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 1: ... p0_.creation_date >= $4 GROUP BY p0_.id ORDER BY l1_.creati...
```

As i can understand, it says that group by column should be in SELECT. I dont it to be there. I need to select just p (AppBundle:Photo) and nothing more. What should be edited in dql to get it working properly?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I just replaced  `ORDER BY l.creationDate DESC` to  `ORDER BY p.creationDate DESC`

It will work for me. As i understood, ORDER BY column should be SELECTed